# Issues with counter and for loop. Assitance appreciated

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

Having issues with my for loops and the counter it should add up each value of the numbers I have added and ask me what that value is, at the end of the for loop.  I added the number-2 to end the loop, so I tried to subtract it from the total before printing, but it doesn't work.
Help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountingCards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counting();
    }

    public static void Counting() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int a = 0; a < 110; a++) {
            int player = rand.nextInt((10) + 1);
            System.out.println("    ");
            System.out.println("You got this card: " + player);
            System.out.println("What is the value of that card");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            if (player == 1) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                    count = -1;
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                    count = -1;
                }
            }
            if (player == 2) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 3) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 4) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 5) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 6) {
                if (answer == -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != -1) {
                    count = -1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 7) {
                if (answer == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 8) {
                if (answer == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 9) {
                if (answer == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }
            if (player == 10) {
                if (answer == 1) {
                    count = 1;
                    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
                }
                if (answer != 1) {
                    count = 1;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
                }
            }

            if (answer == -2) {

                sum = sum - 2;
                System.out.println("Your total count is:  " + sum);
                break;
            }
            sum = sum + count;

        }
    }
}
```

the sum should add all the counters I've acquired, throughout the for loop, and ask me each time to see if the answer I give them adds to the total counter each time. It's ways off and I dont know why

Comment: I think you write something simpler to understand how your code runs/works. I don't "get" this game, is this an actual thing? or did you just modify it to turn it into something else?

Anyway, what I'd also do is remove the second set of IFs. If you test for if (answer == -1), there's no need to test for if (answer != -1). I get that it's more in-your-face, but it's counterintuitive/hard to read. 
Then, if a player can be just one of 1..10, you should add else if, so if (player == 1) else if (player == 2)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here.  It prints a value, then asks what the value is, but it never compares the guess to the initial value?  And what are you trying to sum up?  Total value of random numbers, number of guesses wrong/right?

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand what exactly this game is; but looking at your code, I guessed that you have made a logical mistake in the following line:

```
int player = rand.nextInt((10) + 1);
```

It should be

```
int player = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

Second thing is, you can replace the following code:

```
if (answer == -1) {
    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
    count = -1;
}
if (answer != -1) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
    count = -1;
}
```

with

```
if (answer == -1) {
    System.out.println("That is CORRECT");
    count = -1;
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, that is INCORRECT");
    count = -1;
}
```

For more help, you need to clearly mention the rules of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
int player = rand.nextInt((10) + 1);
```

to

```
int player = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

should solve your problem. Hope it helps..

Have a good day !